# How to synchronize two asynchronous delegate methods callbacks in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I'm writing a simple weather app to try to solidify my understanding of protocols and delegates. I'm in the following situation:

- I have 2 data sources for weather data (Just NSObjects at this time) and a view controller that I want to update once I have received data from **both** sources.
- The 2 data sources have protocols that I adhere to in the view controller. Their delegate methods are called once they have received data from their own web service. This could mean that Data Source 1 gets data before Data Source 2, vice-versa, or at the same time (don't know 100% if this is possible)
- I only want to update the view once I have received data from both sources.

What would be the best way to do this? I was thinking of nesting the delegate methods, where Data source 1 would notify Data source 2 when it has data (through protocols), then have data source 2 notify the view controller to update the view when it has data. However I don't think this is the correct/best way to do things.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you treat the case of Data Source 1 failing and Data Source succeeding? In this case, does Data Source 1 know how to try again?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a good fit for GCD dispatch groups.

First, create a dispatch group with `dispatch_group_create`. Then use `dispatch_group_enter` just before you start the request for each service. Call `dispatch_group_leave` when you receive a response from each service. You can specify what to do when both requests are complete with `dispatch_group_notify`.

The code might look something like this:

```
dispatch_group_t weatherGroup = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(weatherGroup);
[weatherService1 requestWithCompletion:^(Response *response){
    // Do something with the response
    dispatch_group_leave(weatherGroup);
}];

dispatch_group_enter(weatherGroup);
[weatherService2 requestWithCompletion:^(Response *response){
    // Do something with the response
    dispatch_group_leave(weatherGroup);
}];

dispatch_group_notify(weatherGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    // This is executed after both requests are finished
});
```

See the docs for more details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW19

Comment: This is pretty much what I was going to say. You can also use signals/semaphores depending on your needs and tastes.

Answer (score -1):

You can take two BOOL variables *recievedDataFromServiceOne* and *recievedDataFromServiceTwo*. Now set them as soon as your service returns the response and keep and AND operation to check before you refresh the view. After UI freshed reset both to **NO**

```
if(recievedDataFromServiceOne && recievedDataFromServiceTwo) {
   //Refesh the UI
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a counter property that you increment in the delegate methods. So start with the counter at 0, and each delegate method would increment it by 1. You can then observe the value of this counter in the overridden setter for the property (which I call counter)

```
-(void)setCounter:(NSInteger)counter {
    _counter = counter;
    if (_counter == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Both delegates have been called");
        // do your update here
    }
}
```

Comment: "You can then observe the value of this counter in the overridden setter for the property (which I call counter)" - I'm a little confused by what you mean by this? Is this is same as checking the counter (to see if it's 2) after each time I increment it?

Comment: @p0ny, the setter (setCounter:) is called each time you set the value of counter (that's what a setter is), so you don't need to "check it", it will be called when you increment. You need to make sure you use the property syntax when you do the incrementing -- self.counter +=1;